# When Memory profiling is required?

Tags: performance, memory, memory-leaks

Whether its required to do memory/performance profiling on all applications? If not when it should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profile an application when performance does not meet requirements, or when there's a good business reason to focus on optimizing performance (in our case we run dozens of web servers, so every so often we dedicate part of a sprint to performance tuning because there's a real impact to our operations budget by doing so).

It can also be worth profiling applications now and then even if these conditions are not met to help you understand what matters, and what does not, in performance.  Usually though there is a large backlog of software to write, so I would not spend too much time profiling without a specific business reason.  It's easy to spend a LOT of time optimizing things because it's an interesting Engineering challenge rather than because it helps the software really be better to its users.

Comment: Depends... what platform?  For .NET, there are decent tools built in to VS 2010 (2008 and earlier were less good) but Ants Profiler from RedGate is the best in my opinion.  I had some success with the YourKit profiler for Java, but can't say if it's the best or not.  I don't have recommendations for other platforms/languages.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I wanted a tool for application developed using VC++ language.

Comment: C++/CLI (managed C++) or unmanaged C++?  If managed, the tools in Visual Studio should work fine but I have not used them for C++ so am not 100% sure.